# Meta Stack Overflow is the only meta on the network with the "Etiquette" section in the FAQ, it should be in all the metas

Tags: bug, etiquette, per-site-meta, site-faq

I was looking at some of the FAQs on some of the other metas in the network, and I was surprised to see that a great deal don't have them.

However, [Meta Stack Overflow does](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette).

Given that many of the communities on the network are going to stay within their metas when it comes to site governance, and that the etiquette rules apply across the *entire* network, I consider it a bug that it's not included on the site meta's `/faq` (while it *is* included on the main site's `/faq`).

Please include [the etiquette section of the `/faq`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette) in all of the meta sites on the network.

Comment: Would you like the mechanical explanation for this being the way it is, or is your actual intent just to get this changed? I'd suggest it as a feature request if you mean the latter, as the former is quite easily answered in the simplest way imaginable. For what it's worth, I would also support it getting changed.

Comment: @GraceNote Whichever makes you guys feel better about getting it done is fine with me.  The semantics of whether or not it's a bug vs a feature request are irrelevant.  A `status-completed` on this would produce the same output (meaning, I'd like it changed). =)

Answer (score 11):

**That... sounds about right.**

It's obviously meant to apply to all sites.

The per-site meta FAQs are based on a different template, and they're generally a bit condensed vs. the main ones, with the intent on focusing more on the differences between the two (talking about the *site* vs. the *topics*, etc). The assumption is that all the core rules apply to both, but we should make the most important ones more explicit.

We'll look to have it added just to be completely explicit.

Comment: Appreciated.  It seems that we're still on the Internet, so people get heated, especially in metas on the other sites.